# I have two regex's for 1 form. one of them is working, the other is not. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I had tested both expressions and they both worked.   Now, when going over all the code and attachments, I found that the regex for the postal code does not work. (the one for the email addresses does.   I tried some error testing and can't seem to find why it's not working.   I have attached the form data that the regex should take the input from.   When I submit the form, it seems to bypass the postal regex altogether.   Our postal codes are formatted as Letter, Number, Letter (then optional space or dash); followed by Number, letter, number.

```html
 <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <td>
      First Name:<input name="fname" required="required" type="text"/><br />
      Last Name:<input name="lname" required="required" type="text" /><br />
      E-mail address:<input name="email" required="required" input type= "text"/><br />
      Postal Code:<input name="postal" required="required" type="text"/><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Join our Mailing List" onclick="return validate(this.form);"></input>
     </td>
    </tr> 
   </table>
```

Any suggestions?

```js
 <script> 
   var validate = function(myform){
   var postal = myform.postal;
   var regex = /^([A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z] -?\d[A-Za-z])\d$/i;
    if (!regex.test(postal.value))
     {
     alert("invalid postal code format");
     return false;
     }     
    return confirm("continue?");
     } 
  </script>
  <script> 
   var validate = function(myform){
   var myemail = myform.email;
   var regex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/i;
    if (!regex.test(myemail.value))
     {
     alert("invalid email format");
     return false;
     }
    return confirm("continue?");
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: *One regex is not working* is a bit thin coming to descriptions of wanted and observed behaviour. I don't know the New Zealand postal codes - can you give examples of a few valid ones, and at least one "almost valid one" *with an explanation how to detect it is invalid*?

Comment: our postal codes are letter, number, letter, then a space or hyphen; followed by a number, letter, numer   eg  T3G 3c6

Comment: `space or hyphen` in the regex, I read *space, followed by an optional hyphen*. Not quite sure what the parentheses excluding the last digit will do.

Comment: when I submit the form, it seems to bypass this regex but not the one for my email address

Comment: (erm - isn't `/[A-Za-z])/i` overdoing ignorance of character case?)

Comment: good point greybeard.   I don't need the lowercase a-z.   Also, thanks for the reminder to include all the details in the question.   I'm new.  :)

Comment: `<space>-?` should be `[ -]?`

Comment: for shits and giggles, I tried putting the postal code regex underneath the other one in the code.   In that case, It catches the postal code regex, but not the email one.   Can I only have one or the other in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the function to validate the form in the variable `validate`. You assign two different functions to that variable. One for checking the postal code, the other for checking the email address.

Assigning the second function overwrites the reference of the first function. So, only the check for email address will be executed. Include both checks in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the duplicate definition of `validate` function.

```html
<form>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
        First Name:<input name="fname" required="required" type="text"/><br />
        Last Name:<input name="lname" required="required" type="text" /><br />
        E-mail address:<input name="email" required="required" input type= "text"/><br />
        Postal Code:<input name="postal" required="required" type="text"/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Join our Mailing List" onclick="return validate(this.form);"></input>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</form>
<script> 
var validate = function(myform) {
var postal = myform.postal;
var regex = /^([A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z] -?\d[A-Za-z])\d$/i;
if (!regex.test(postal.value)) {
    alert("invalid postal code format");
    return false;
}     

var myemail = myform.email;
var regex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/i;
if (!regex.test(myemail.value)) {
    alert("invalid email format");
    return false;
}
return confirm("continue?");
}
</script>
```